# Checking for NaN condition not working

Tags: javascript, nan

On my `Page_load` I am using one JS function. By Default it is showing me `NaN` So I have added a condition for checking `NaN` like below

```
var totalPaid = document.getElementById('txttotalPaid').value;
        var totLandVal = 0;

        totLandVal = parseInt(Expense) + parseInt(totalPaid)

        if (totLandVal == 0 || totLandVal == NaN) {

            document.getElementById('txtTotalLandVal').value = 0;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('txtTotalLandVal').value = totLandVal;
        }
```

But the value is still coming `Nan` in the textbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead, because surprise:

```
NaN == NaN  // false
```

Comment: like this `if (totLandVal == 0 || totLandVal == isNaN()) {` ?

Comment: `isNaN(totLandVal)`. Take a look at the MDN reference I included along with an explanation of why this function is needed.

Comment: superb, that worked. Also suprised in so much less time u got so much Upvotes :P

Comment: In case you need backward compatibility, `totLandVal != totLandVal` will be `true` if and only if `totLandVal` is `NaN`.

Comment: is something special with your answer `because surprise:` ??

Comment: one thing more, the same function works on my PC which is `IE11` but same thing doesn't works on my mate's PC with same browser version. Any idea why ?

Comment: `.isNaN` was added in ES5. If the browser you are using is very old then there is a chance it will not work. In that case you should check with `totLandVal != totLandVal` instead.

Comment: it is not related to `IsNan`. earlier also it was not working on my Mate's PC  when I was not using `IsNan`

Comment: You should submit another question regarding that.

Answer (score 3):

Just change `totLandVal == NaN` to [`isNaN(totLandVal)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (totLandVal == 0 || totLandVal == NaN)
```

for

```
if ( totLandVal == 0 || isNaN(totLandVal) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
var totalPaid = document.getElementById('txttotalPaid').value;
        var totLandVal = 0;

        totLandVal = parseInt(Expense) + parseInt(totalPaid)

        if (totLandVal == 0 || isNaN(totLandVal)) {

            document.getElementById('txtTotalLandVal').value = 0;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('txtTotalLandVal').value = totLandVal;
        }
```